# Why I am getting Generic Xcode Archive while generating ipa?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, archive, ipa

I am getting This Error While Creating .ipa file With Xcode 6.1.1. I have Checked Build Settings as Well:

- 1.Skip install is NO for the main project target
- Skip install is YES for framework (sub-projects) targets
- In Build Phases for sub-projects, Copy Headers needs to be in Project, not Public (does not apply if building static library)
- Installation Directory under Deployment is valid (/Applications for example)

Please check the screenshot as well.
[image]

Comment: Have you selected the right build scheme, target and device (i.e. you cannot archive when building for simulator)?

Comment: Yes I have Take Care of all the Things.I have selected proper Scheme and In device i have select iOS Device.Please suggest If any thing missing.

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode 7 with iOS 9, this was happening to me because an issue with the Cocoapods version I was using (0.38.2). The issue is described here:

https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4087

I was able to get past this by upgrading to the latest cocoapods beta.